# Why does using the IF-ENDIF block in this DB2 function cause

Tags: db2, db2-400

Why does using the IF statement in this function result in error 42601 [SQL0104], as shown below..? This is DB2-400 for i v7r3m0.

`SQL Error [42601]: [SQL0104] Token <END-OF-STATEMENT> was not valid. Valid tokens: ;.`

The code example I provide below executes without error until the IF statement is uncommented. I've tried moving the semicolons around and even removing them, but then the errors get worse and begin pointing to later statements being invalid.

I've checked the [IBM documentation for IF on v7r3](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzifstmt.htm), and my syntax seems to be correct. [Other code examples](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzloopstmt.htm) follow the same syntax as that and mine. I'm stumped.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_CERT.CERT_UPC_COMMON_DESC (UPC NUMERIC(14))
    RETURNS INTEGER
    LANGUAGE SQL
    GLOBAL DETERMINISTIC
    NO EXTERNAL ACTION
    NOT FENCED
    ALLOW PARALLEL
BEGIN

    DECLARE RETVAL      INTEGER DEFAULT 0 ;
    DECLARE UPC_COUNT   INTEGER DEFAULT 0 ;

    DECLARE UPC_LIST CURSOR FOR
        SELECT      COUNT(*)
        FROM        F_CERTOB.BEERXT
        WHERE       BXUPCR=UPC
        ;

    OPEN  UPC_LIST ;
    FETCH UPC_LIST INTO UPC_COUNT ;
    CLOSE UPC_LIST ;

--    IF UPC_COUNT > 0 THEN
--        -- OTHER
--        -- COMMANDS
        SET RETVAL = UPC_COUNT ;
--    END IF ;

    RETURN RETVAL ;

END ;

SELECT F_CERT.CERT_UPC_COMMON_DESC (793936791660) AS C FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 ;
```

EDIT:

Here is a second example; a trimmed-down version. As with the code above, everything is fine until the IF statements are uncommented:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_CERT.CERT_UPC_COMMON_DESC (UPC NUMERIC(14))
    RETURNS INTEGER
    LANGUAGE SQL

BEGIN

    DECLARE RETVAL INTEGER DEFAULT 0 ;

--    IF 1=1 THEN
        SET RETVAL = 1 ;
--    ELSE
        SET RETVAL = 100 ;
--    END IF ;

    RETURN RETVAL ;
END ;

SELECT F_CERT.CERT_UPC_COMMON_DESC (12345) AS C FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 ;
```

Comment: At the suggestion of @Mark-Barinstein I edited my code above and added a new declared variable and `SET RETVAL = UPC_COUNT` and so `RETURN RETVAL` is the last statement in the function. Unfortunately this does not help and the error still occurs when the IF statements are uncommented. I also added a second smaller block of code that focuses closely on the problem.

Comment: I created your simplified version on our system with the IF statements uncommented and it worked just fine.  We are on V7R1.

Comment: I'm on to something. It seems to be an issue with the statement terminator character in my SQL client "DBeaver". I finally got it to work, but with some trickery. I'm still reading about it and experimenting. I'll post my own answer once I figure it out.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your function definitions.  I also replaced the SET RETVAL commands with direct RETURN statements and it worked just as well.  As you said in your last comment, it probably has to do with your client.

Comment: Yes, the issue is flow control and similar statements that span multiple lines. I've figured it out and posted my own answer to my OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've continued searching since my OP, and I finally found the exact solution 
[here](https://learningintheopen.org/2018/09/12/dbeaver-editor-customization-statement-delimiter/).

The issue is the statement delimiter. A conflict arises when the function contains flow-control and similarly structured statements that span multiple lines. In my code example, the compiler stops at `END IF;` and thinks that's all there is, instead of continuing to the `END;` of the function.

My SQL client is DBeaver 5.2.5, and it does have some functionality to run statements & scripts in different ways. [This article](https://dbeaver.io/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=669) gave me the idea to try running my `CREATE` script with the different actions of DBeaver, and I discovered I could make it work if I highlighted the whole script from `CREATE` to `END` *but not including the trailing semicolon*. Then I used `Execute Statement {Ctrl+Enter}` instead of the usual `Execute Sctipt {Alt+X}`. And it finally worked..!! But that seemed "kludgy" so I continued searching for a solution.

Then I found the imperfect, but perfectly acceptable solution in the [main article](https://learningintheopen.org/2018/09/12/dbeaver-editor-customization-statement-delimiter/) mentioned above. I followed the directions to change the settings in my DBeaver client, and edited my code as shown below (notice the `@` characters). And then it finally worked..!! I could run the whole script, including the `SELECT` statement, and was able to do so with the usual `Execute Statement {Alt+X}` keystroke that I've become accustomed to.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_CERT.CERT_UPC_COMMON_DESC (UPC NUMERIC(14))
    RETURNS INTEGER
    LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
    DECLARE RETVAL INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    IF 1=0 THEN
        SET RETVAL = 1;
    ELSE
        SET RETVAL = 100;
    END IF;
    RETURN RETVAL;
END @ 

SELECT F_CERT.CERT_UPC_COMMON_DESC (793936791660) AS C FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 @
```